# Get NSString From NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try to get `NSString` from `NSURL` with this method:

```
NSString *tmp2 = [item.path absoluteString];
```

Unfortunately I get instead of the NSURL:

```
<CFURL 0x173c50 [0x3f1359f8]>{type = 0, string = /var/mobile/Applications/A30FD2E4-A273-4522-AFD5-A981EFD3C2AA/Documents/*** *** - *** ***.***, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}
```

I get :

```
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/A30FD2E4-A273-4522-AFD5-A981EFD3C2AA/Documents/***%20***%20-%20***%20***.***
```

any idea why?

Comment: If you're looking for what you would get by doing `po item` (where item is a NSURL) in gdb, then you should call `[item description]`.  Not sure why you want the NSUrl.  Are you just looking to build a persistence layer?

Comment: You are saying that you want to get a string out of a URL and that is exactly what you are getting - what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that i get "%20" instead of " "

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [NSURL documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/absoluteString) clearly states that `absoluteString` returns an NSString, just like your code above. This is the string representation of the absolute path, so what you are getting is what you should be getting.

However, looking at the documentation you could also use [`path`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path), [`relativePath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/relativePath) or [`relativeString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/relativeString) to get a string representation of the url in other formats (absolute or relative paths that either do or do not conform to [RFC 1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808) (a now obsolete [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)).